# Remote Debugging Website on LG WebOS Browser

Tags: browser, remote-debugging, webos, lg

Is there any possibility to debug a Website remotely, which is open on an LG TVs Browser? I found some solutions to debug my own WebOS App with Visual Studio Code, but i want to debug the WebOS internal Browser.

The Reason for this is, that there is a website which has issues only when dsiplaying it on the LG internalal Webbrowser.

I also tried it with the "ares-inspect" command from the WebOS CLI, but i think its only possible to debug your own App with the known AppID.

I hope someone can help me out here ...

Edit 1:

In the meantime i figured out the AppID of the Internal Browser and tried to connect via ares to it:

```
    ares-inspect -a com.webos.app.browser -d tv
Session#forward() failed forwarding client localPort: 0 (inCnx.remotePort: 65530 )=> devicePort: 9998
ares-inspect WARN Session#forward() failed forwarding client localPort: 0 => devicePort: 9998
Session#forward() failed forwarding client localPort: 0 (inCnx.remotePort: 65531 )=> devicePort: 9998
ares-inspect WARN Session#forward() failed forwarding client localPort: 0 => devicePort: 9998
Application Debugging - http://localhost:49576
```

When i open the URL (http://localhost:49576) in (for my WebOS version corresponding) Chromium Browser i only get this Screen:

[image: Screenshot of browser]

Comment: Did you later host it as a web app? How did you solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I suggest is building a hosted web app as is described here: https://webostv.developer.lge.com/develop/getting-started/web-app-types

Because a hosted app uses the same browser engine as the regular browser on WebOS. But you will have the benefit of making debugging easy.

You get use this example project to get started quickly: https://github.com/webOS-TV-app-samples/HostedWebApp

Replace the URL within `index.html` with the URL from your own project. If you use a locally run dev server, insert the ip address of your computer. eg. http://192.168.1.2:8080.

Install it on your WebOS tv, run it and then execute `ares-inspect -a com.sample.hosted -d tv` from your computer to start the inspector

Now you should be able to read the console messages

Comment: Thank you, all is working fine except the website i want to inspect. The website uses the Jquery library and when i open it through a hosted web app i get an Javascript error: $window is not defined. I guess this happens because its different from running in a regular webbrowser?

Comment: No it is not different. It should work. `$window` is probably undefined, but `$` or `window` should be. But most likely you meant to use `$(window)`

Comment: Another tip: you could also download the same Chromium version as is used on WebOS. You can easily find the specific version as a standalone file for macOS or Windows. This makes initial development way more easier. If you work with the WebOS JavaScript SDK you should definitely move to WebOS itself.

Comment: you mean i can run WebOS as some kind of VM on my own Computer?

Comment: No that is not what I meant. You can install the Chromium browser on your computer to 'simulate' the browser on your WebOS device. It is not 1 on 1 but quite identical in features. WebOS also has it's own simulator which you can try out. But it doesn't has a regular browser. So you need to use the hosted app method for that. The WebOS simulator has an Inspector button availible on the on-screen remote. Definitely recommended to try it out.